# Gradle: Configure distribution task for select sub projects

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi project gradle build. I want to configure distribution task only for 2 of the sub projects.

Lets assume I have a root project and sub projects A, B & C. I want to configure distribution task for B & C only.

The following way works:
**root_project/build.gradle**

```
subprojects{

   configure ([project(':B'), project(":C")]) {

       apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'
       distributions {
       main {
            contents {
                from('src/main/') {
                    include 'bin/*'
                    include 'conf/**'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am interested in making it work this way

```
subprojects{

   configure (subprojects.findAll {it.hasProperty('zipDistribution') && it.zipDistribution}) ) {

       apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'
       distributions {
       main {
            contents {
                from('src/main/') {
                    include 'bin/*'
                    include 'conf/**'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in build.gradle for B & C, I will have the following:

```
ext.zipDistribution = true
```

In the latter approach I have the following 2 problems:

**Problem 1**

```
* What went wrong:
Task 'distZip' not found in root project 'root_project'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
```

**Problem 2**

I tried to verify whether the property `zipDistribution` can be read in the root_project with the following code

```
subprojects {
    .....
//    configure ([project(':B'), project(":C")]) {

        apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'
        distributions {
            /* Print if the property exists */

            println it.hasProperty('zipDistribution')
            main {
                contents {
                    from('src/main/') {
                        include 'bin/*'
                        include 'conf/**'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
//    }

      .....
}
```

The above prints null for it.hasProperty('zipDistribution').

Can someone let me what is the right approach so that I do not see these problems?

Comment: Problem 1 - just check if task 'distZip' exists in appropriate project. Problem 2 - this is because of build lifecycle. Add this code and you will see that properties are listed: `task checkSubprojectsProperties << { subprojects { println it.zipDistribution} }`. As you can see this code is run in execution phase.

Comment: @PatrykRoszczyniała For problem 2, is there a solution by which I configure distZip task for a subproject only if it has a property 'distributionZip'?

Answer (score 1):

This is because subprojects are configured *after* the root project. Which is why `ext.zipDistribution` is `null` at that point in time (it hasn't been set yet).

You need to use `afterEvaluate` to avoid that:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('zipDistribution') && project.zipDistribution) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```